# How long can I extend my visa exempt stay as a US citizen visiting Colombia?

Tags: visas, usa, us-citizens, colombia

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_United_States_citizens) (WP) and "[retire in the caribbean](https://www.retireinthecaribbean.com/)" (RC) both say US citizens are visa-exempt for 90 day visit.

WP says it can be extended up to 180 days; RC says 90.  WP cites a state department page that does **not** mention extension.  RC has no cite.  WP also cites Colombian government document that does **not** mention extension.

RC says must have a return ticket, which is a nuisance if one extends (yes, I understand the trick of canceling a refundable ticket later; still a nuisance).

**How much extension is possible?  Official source?**

Comment: If the 90 days can be extended *as a given* and it is your firm intention to obtain the extension, can you not book a return ticket with your actual intended date of return? I have done that many times for trips to Cuba, where  a 30 day extension is ‘guaranteed’ for visitors.

Comment: I could do that too, but ideally, I'd like to just go and leave when I've seen enough.  Plus, I'm trying to compile data on the requirements of many countries.

Comment: The extension in both cases is 90 days. Wikipedia states "extendable up to 180-days stay within a one-year period" so that's a 90-day extension on the original 90-day visa. The link from Wikipedia **does** mention an extension. Look in the Entry, Exit, and Visa requirements section farther down on the page.

Comment: When I look, I do see the mention of an extension.  Interestingly, even with that section expanded, Safari's search-in-page feature says the page does not contain the word extension.  Anyway, our government isn't exactly an official source for another country, but it's close enough.  :-)  Thanks.